# Does PIP deployment install secondary packages required by those listed in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, anaconda

I'm a bit confused my a remark in the documentation for PIP requirements ("Requirement files are *mostly* flat") and just want to confirm in case it is doing anything different from what I expect.

Does PIP/requriments.txt deployment install packages required by those listed in requirements.txt? For example if my requirements.txt file has

```
some_pkg=1.2.3
```

and `some_pkg` has dependencies on several other packages, `pkg_a`, `pkg_b`, and `pkg_c`, will those three packages also be installed? Does a package have to be listed in requirements.txt PIP install it when deploying? Can the listing of `some_pkg` in requrements.txt ever trigger the installation of packages not listed there?

Comment: `pip` will usually install the subdependencies—assuming it can find them all.

Comment: @JohnMee: That's the answer then.